# Prevent an observable from being set in specific cases

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, overloading

Is it possible to overload the setter on observable to prevent setting its value in some cases? Say with a function which will trigger before setting observable, like this:

```
function(value) {
    if (value === 'ok') {
        proceed; //set value of observable
    } else {
        break; //do not set observable
    }
}
```

I guess that it can be achieved by using subscriptions, but I am not fully aware how.

Not that I'm using knockout 3.0.

Comment: If you write what exactly you are trying to do and explain your case, you could get better answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [writable computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) with `read` and `write` functions:

```
var _prop = ko.observable();

var prop = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return _prop();
    },
    write: function(value ) {
        if (value === 'ok') {
            _prop(value); //set value of observable
        }
        // else do not set observable
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 but recommend that _prop is itself an observable, not just a plain value.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker That depends on intended usage, right? In some cases the overhead may not be worth it, e.g. if you don't have any other/direct dependencies on `_prop`.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker, agree with Jeroen, `_prop` will most of the time be the private backing field and `prop` the observable to bind to.

Comment: Here's what I'm talking about: http://jsbin.com/zuvujutazi/1/edit?html,js,output - if you don't use an observable for `_prop` (as in the top/red example) then no change notifications will come out of `prop` when its value changes.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker, you are right, computed will notify changes only if they track observables. When using a plain js variable as backing field, nothing is tracked. Answer fixed.

Comment: But is it possible to achieve it with subscriptions? I have already this observable in my autogenerated viewmodel and if possible I wouldn't like to change that observable into computed.

Comment: subscription are not meant to be used for this. You can however follow the solution in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691374/how-might-i-cancel-a-change-to-an-observable-array-w-knockout-3-0) which may help you. Can't you add a computed observable to your autogenerated viewmodel that uses the existing old observable?